# Data at rest encryption

Tags: autodesk-forge

I've been looking for info on how/if Forge encrypts data at rest. We have some customers with sensitive models that are asking the question.

1. Is data at rest encrytped?
2. If so, what method of encrypted is used and is it on by default?
3. If not, is this a planned feature in the future?

Comment: The further question is if it is encrypted how is the encryption key secured?

Answer (score 1):

The Forge REST API is using https which means you are using the SSL protocol to transfer data between the client and server (both way). SSL encrypts the data for you automatically using the 'trusted' certificate. Here is a [complete article](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work) on the protocol if you interested reading more about it.

Edited based on comments below - if we are talking about storage, all the data stored on the Forge servers are encrypted with your developer keys. Forge encrypts your data at the object level as it writes it to disks and decrypts it for you when you access it.

Comment: By "data at rest" I assume he actually means the data that is being stored on Forge ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_at_rest

Comment: Actually TLS, not SSL which is deprecated. But as Philippe states, HTTPS is not data at rest but data in transit and the encryption necessary is substantially different.

Comment: Right, we are curious about how Forge stores the model data once it reaches the Forge servers. When it is stored is buckets, can the data be encrypted?